'cp950' codec can't encode character '\u2501' in position 19: illegal multibyte sequence when keras.predict()
This is my code:
if __name__ == "__main__":

    audio_data = record_audio(sr, duration)
    processed_audio = process_audio(audio_data, sr)

    print("shape", processed_audio.shape)  
    model = keras.saving.load_model("LSTM_P_CNN//LSTM_P_CNN.keras")  # corrected loading method
    print(0)
    vggish_features = vggish(audio_data).numpy()
    print(1)
    print(vggish_features.shape)
    print("Model Input Shape:", model.input_shape)
    print("Model Output Shape:", model.output_shape)
    v1 = vggish_features.reshape(1, vggish_features.shape[0], vggish_features.shape[1], 1)
    v2 = vggish_features.reshape(1, vggish_features.shape[0], vggish_features.shape[1], 1)
    print(type(v1))
    try:
        model.summary()
        x = model.predict([v1, v2])
        print(x)
        print(type(x))
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)

And this is my output:
0
1
(93, 128)
Model Input Shape: [(None, 93, 128, 1), (None, 93, 128)]
Model Output Shape: (None, 10)
An error occurred: 'cp950' codec can't encode character '\u2501' in position 19: illegal multibyte sequence


U+2501 is BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY HORIZONTAL(━) and is not supported by the CP950 (Traditional Chinese)  code page, which appears to be the encoding supported by your terminal display.  If using an IDE, switch to UTF-8.  It's probably caused by print(x) but the full traceback of the error is being hidden by the try/except.

Thank you for giving me the possible reasons.However,I tried not to print x and got the same error. I think maybe the problem come from the model(.keras file).

Remove the try/except and see the full traceback.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Lowen\Downloads\music_style\music_style\main.py", line 263, in 
x = model.predict([v1, v2])
File "D:\anaconda\envs\music_style\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "D:\anaconda\envs\music_style\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\io_utils.py", line 98, in print_msg
sys.stdout.write(message)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp950' codec can't encode character '\u2501' in position 19: illegal multibyte sequence

This is the output when I remove the try except

You should [edit] the question to include the traceback and the code used to generate it. It looks like keras is trying to print an error message that includes the bad code point.
